# How to inject services into view/viewmodel using Ninject in MVC3?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, service-locator

I am using MVC3 with Ninject, Dependencies in my controller are resolved with no problem. I have few services like localization, format provider and I want them to be injected into view models or Razor views. Right now I am manually injecting them to my View Models,

1. How can I automate this?
2. Can I inject some services to Razor views?
3. How do I setup service locator using Ninject in MVC?

**For others:**
It seems like Service Locator is bad idea because, Ninjects Bootstrapper.Kernel is obsolete and Service Locator is an anti pattern. Check out this article http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

_

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //This gets injected correctly
    [Inject]
    public ILocalizationService LocalizationService { get; set; }

    //This gets injected correctly
    [Inject]
    public MyModel Model { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var modelResult = Model.GetStuff();
        //Here I am manully injecting my services to my View Model,
        //I would like Ninject to inject services into my view model.
        var viewModelResult = IndexViewModel.Covert(LocalizationService, modelResult);
        return View(viewModelResult);
    }


    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Ninject's MVC 3 plugin, it is pretty good about creating all the hooks that are available. I *think* there's support for Razor views: if you create a class that extends the typical View class and add injected dependencies to that class, I think Ninject will be able to inject those items so that they will be available to you in the View.

For my views, I've preferred to use custom HtmlHelper-based extension methods that end up indirectly using a singleton-based Service Locator pattern to access the appropriate dependencies. If you're finding that it doesn't make sense to say `Html.MyMethod(...)` or `Url.MyMethod(...)` or something like that, there's a strong probability that the item you're trying to include does not belong in your View.

Likewise, Model objects should generally just be POCOs, with a minimal amount of logic associated with them. Populating them with services sounds like a violation of the MVC model. As Jason points out, you could just set the format providers on the model from the controller's code. However, I'd say it's even better to use the format providers to generate the strings you're going to need and put `those` on the model instead.

#### Response to comments on Jason's post

Approach 1 sounds like a good idea, as it sounds like your controller is getting complex and this is a good place to separate a concern into a different class. If you inject the `Converter` itself into your controller rather than using it as a static class, then its dependencies will automatically be injected when Ninject is creating the controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Inject]
    public ViewModelConverter Converter { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public MyModel Model { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var modelResult = Model.GetStuff();
        var viewModelResult = Converter.MakeViewModel(modelResult);
        return View(viewModelResult);
    }


    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class ViewModelConverter
{
    [Inject]
    public ILocalizationService LocalizationService { get; set; }
    
    public ViewModel MakeViewModel(MyModel model)
    {
        // You should be able to use LocalizationService here
    }
}
```

I stuck with your property-based injection on this, even though I'd personally prefer using constructor injection.

Comment: just like to highlight the sentence, "there's a strong probability that the item you're trying to include does not belong in your View".  the point of the controllers is to do the formatting and processing and get the ViewModel all set up so the view can use it as-is.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior See my comments to Jason's answers.

Comment: @iraSenthil: See my response in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inject the format providers into the controller and then set them on the ViewModel when it is created.

Comment: i can't tell from the code sample, but in your question you specifically said you want to inject into the view model.  i think that's a bad plan.  If you've got the format providers in your controller, then you should simply set the string properties on your model as StriplingWarrior suggests.  You should be golden.

Comment: I have two choices here to implement these transformation **1.** Puristic approach[at least in my mind] Create Converter[class] that takes model as input and transform into ViewModel that has formatted/localized values and view simply displays it. This what I am doing now, ViewModel does two things DTO for View and conversion from Model **2.** Doing these conversion in controller, I think this approach is little ugly because controller does many things and makes my TDD harder.

Comment: So the question is, How do I automatically inject services into these Converters? Can I expose readonly Ninject Kernel to resolve these services?

Comment: i don't really know the specifics of Ninject.  In general I don't think you want your ViewModel to do anything, it should be a simple property bag.  You would want some other mechanism for doing the conversion.  I'm not sure why you think doing conversion in the controller is ugly.  It's the logical place to set model properties.  Just make sure the conversion logic is a service being used by the controller.

Comment: **>>I'm not sure why you think doing conversion in the controller is ugly.** My conversion logic is complex, placing it in controller would make my Unit testing life hard. So I had to move that logic to a separate place. I could have created separate converter that knows about model and view model if I wanted to be a puristic. Just for sake of simplicity I kept those conversion in ViewModel.